Can a Grothendieck universe be defined as a set which is a model of ZFC?
Let us assume for this question that a Grothendieck universe always contains the set of natural numbers.
We have the following fact: If $\mathbb{U}$ is a Grothendieck universe, then we get a model of ZFC set theory by defining "set" to be an element of $\mathbb{U}$.
Now suppose we try to use the above fact to define a Grothendieck universe: A Grothendieck universe is a set $\mathbb{U}$ which is a model of ZFC when "set" is defined to be an element of $\mathbb{U}$. Is that definition correct?

It’s not obvious to me that a Grothendieck universe has to satisfy choice, so it’s not obvious to me that $\Bbb N \in \Bbb U$ is enough to ensure that $\Bbb U \Vdash \mathsf {ZFC}$.

@Robert, that a Grothendieck universe satisfies choice follows from this (section 3). OP, section 6 in the page I linked is probably the closest thing to what you're trying to do. Your proposed definition is not equivalent to being a Grothendieck universe. For example, there are countable transitive models of ZFC, and these can't be Grothendieck universes. This page gives a whole list of things in between your definition and inaccessible cardinals (AKA Grothendieck universes).

@IzaakvanDongen based on my naive thinking it seems that $\mathbb{U}$ being a model of ZFC would automatically imply the Grothendieck universe axioms here. Which of the axioms (1) - (4) are not necessarily satisfied?

If $(M, \in)$ is a countable transitive model, then axiom (3) must fail, because the true powerset of the naturals cannot belong to the model (otherwise it would be uncountable). The fact that $M$ models ZFC only tells you that there is an $X \in M$ such that "$Y \in M$ and $Y \subseteq \Bbb N$" is equivalent to "$Y \in X$", whereas for $X$ to be the true powerset, the "$Y \in M$" part would have to be removed. This is a subtle point about first-order logic! Further reading here.

@IzaakvanDongen Thank you for the clarification. I think I am incorrectly using the word "model". Is there different technical term (to replace "model") where we do use the "true power set"?

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks.  Choice follows from the existence of arbitrary Cartesian products, right?

@NickMertes It is definable as a transitive model of 2nd-order ZFC (modulo the inclusion of $\emptyset$ and $V_\omega$, according to the definition in the wikipedia article).

@spaceisdarkgreen Thank you, I think that is the answer I was looking for. Now that I know the correct words to use, it looks like this question has been answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328568/can-second-order-zfc-have-a-set-model. Just one more thing -- do you have any textbook recommendations for this topic?

@NickMertes I don't think I've ever seen a proof given of this in a textbook or (modern) paper. This paper gives a sketch that is much at the same level as Mark's answer. It also does give a reference to the original proof by Zermelo in 1930, though I don't know if that would be any more elucidating.
